# How to implement backup link via VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, failover, mikrotik

I have a PTP wireless network from one location to another and it is working well. I would like to have a VPN backup in case it should ever go down.

How can I make this happen automatically? I am using MikroTik routers and I already set up the VPN, but if my PTP link goes down, how can I fail over to the VPN? Is this doable?

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGK1F.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can consider to use bonding on the end-point devices to be able to access the network from inside if something goes wrong.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/tsafm/4.1.0?topic=interfaces-interface-bonding

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a routing protocol over the wireless link, you can create a "floating static" route over the VPN with higher distance value.  The wireless will be preferred, but the VPN will be used if the wireless goes down.

If everything is static, you need some method to tell if the wireless link is alive.  That will be used to trigger a different route.

Sorry if that last paragraph sounds vague, it's because I'm unfamiliar with the specific Microtik commands.